The hostname_script is not setting ec2 instance name
I am passing below user_data to aws_instance resource and found the host didn't get renamed as per the my requirement
user_data = jsonencode({
cluster_name            = local.cluster_name,
node_hostname_tmpl      = "{node_num:02d}.${local.cluster_name}.${local.hosting_env_dns_internal_zone_name}",
node_num                = each.key + 1,
cluster_cfg             = var.data_fabric_cluster_node_bootstrap_cfg,
data_block_dev_paths    = var.data_fabric_cluster_node_data_block_devs.paths,
mapr_password           = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.mapr_password_secret_ver.secret_string,
nodes_ssh_host_pubkeys  = local.host_pub_key_concatenated,
nodes_ssh_user_pubkeys  = local.user_pub_key_concatenated,
ssh_host_privkey        = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.host_pri_key_ver\[each.key\].secret_string,
ssh_host_pubkey         = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.host_pub_key_ver\[each.key\].secret_string,
ssh_user_privkey        = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.user_pri_key_ver\[each.key\].secret_string,
ssh_user_pubkey         = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.user_pub_key_ver\[each.key\].secret_string,
hostname_script         = \<\<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$(printf '%02d' $((each.key + 1))).${local.cluster_name}.${local.region}
IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
hostname $HOSTNAME
echo "$IP $HOSTNAME" \>\> /etc/hosts
echo 'preserve_hostname: true' \>\> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
echo $HOSTNAME \> /etc/hostname
hostnamectl set-hostname $HOSTNAME
EOF
})


I tried to set hostname but the hostname is not getting updated and is getting default aws ec2 naming.

A script will only only run if the first line begins with #!. Where/how are you running the above code? Did you look in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log?
